# Login Amplify Studio Error "UnexpectedLambdaException: DefineAuthChallenge invocation failed due to error AccessDeniedException."

Tags: aws-amplify

> Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Chrome Console:**

```
POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ 400

Error fetching auto logging in: UnexpectedLambdaException: DefineAuthChallenge invocation failed due to error AccessDeniedException.at https://us-west-1.admin.amplifyapp.com/static/js/458.3019efe9.chunk.js:2:1671303
```

This is useing web-client to login，my account was previously restricted due to security issues. After solving this problem，I can't login in Amplify Studio.And I could not invite team members via email so they can access Amplify Studio.

I think the problem may be is Cognito, but when I try to backup database data, It reminds me:

> IAM Role arn:aws:iam::278463271169:role/service-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole does not have sufficient permissions to execute the backup

So I think it may be the problem of role permissions， and I try to check IAM Role Permissions

**AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole:**

- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup
- AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForRestores

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Cognito user pool that Studio deploys may have gotten into a bad state. If you disable Studio in the Amplify console and then re-enable it, that should fix the issue. You won't lose anything except any users previously created to access the Studio console.